# problem i'm getting (random order) after select images from gallery

Tags: android, image, select

after select multi images from gallery on order selection   the images goes to the recycle view on random order not as I select on specific order or sort. for example  if I select B then A then C  but the code always bring them with random sort or order like A C B and sometimes C A B. . the order seems undefined at first I thought  android sort them based on date and time added to the gallery or what their name i mean alphabet letter but then I realize the order seems undefined. i'm not sure if  I need to add listener with array track the user selections. any suggestion

```
ArrayList imagesUriArrayList;
public static final int slect_photo = 100;
Bitmap bitmap1 = null;
RecyclerView rec;
LinearLayoutManager lnm;
Adopter_Browse list;
ArrayList<MyCard> mylist;

 public void Onclick_View(View view) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);//
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);

    startActivityForResult(intent, slect_photo);
}


  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {


        if (data.getData() != null) {//data.getData() != null) {
   
                imagesUriArrayList = null;
                imagesUriArrayList = new ArrayList();

      try{
                for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {

                    imagesUriArrayList.add(data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri());

                    
                }


                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


            try {

                for (int i = 0; i < imagesUriArrayList.size(); i++) {
                     
                     

                    bitmap1 = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), (Uri) imagesUriArrayList.get(i));
                    mylist.add(new MyCard(count_s, bitmap1));

                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            
          

            lnm = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false);

            list = new Adopter_Browse(mylist);

            rec.setLayoutManager(lnm);

            list.notifyDataSetChanged();
            rec.setAdapter(list);
        }
```

Comment: no one can give chunk of hint how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

I found out that using  onActivityResult that provided by google will always return the order of your selection on miss , so maybe a bug or need improve .

I got two option :
1- using  ItemTouchHelper   library ...  helped me to solve  my problem !
2- gradle source form githup !

I share this maybe some one can  get relief !